# How to fetch apk icons

Tags: apk

Is there any way to show application icon of apk file in explorer.exe just like how the .exe icons were fetched. I have many apk files in my pc but when finding any one it is very hard to find it with its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want : https://code.google.com/p/apkshellext/

Just install it as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to retrieve package icons through [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) class.

Example:

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
    Drawable icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.packageName);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(icon);
}
```

Comment: In explorer.exe (Windows), not in Android. ;)